# Java MongoDB numberLong query - Unable to fetch records

Tags: java, mongodb

I wanted to fetch records between 1 date to other date from mongodb collection, where dates are stored as long in currenttimemillis. So I specified the query in java as

```
BasicDBObject query1 = new BasicDBObject();

long startGracePeriodInMillis = 1651676700254;
long endGracePeriodInMillis = 1653466067550;

query1.put("updated_at", new BasicDBObject("$gt", endGracePeriodInMillis).append("$lt", startGracePeriodInMillis));
```

this query1 is forming as

```
{"updated_at": {"$gt": {"$numberLong": "1653466067550"}, "$lt": {"$numberLong": "1651676700254"}}}
```

but im unable to fetch records, as the date is coming as string with $numberLong .. Im able to get records by mentioning only long without numberLong on server directly with

```
{"updated_at": {"$gt": 1653466067550, "$lt": 1651676700254}}
```

So what change should i need to make in

```
query1.put("updated_at", new BasicDBObject("$gt", endGracePeriodInMillis).append("$lt", startGracePeriodInMillis));
```

to form the query as

```
{"updated_at": {"$gt": 1653466067550, "$lt": 1651676700254}}
```

in the query it should come as only number like "$gt": 1653466067550 (which is giving results) but it is coming as "$gt": {"$numberLong": "1653466067550" - which is creating problem

Answer (score 0):

You have start time and end time, you should search between them:

```
query1.put("updated_at", new BasicDBObject("$gt", startGracePeriodInMillis)
.append("$lt", endGracePeriodInMillis));
```

Not the other way around...
You are now searching for records that are **after** your end time or **before** your start time.

`$gt` means "greater than", you probably want to find documents with `updated_at` greater than your startGracePeriodInMillis...Same with `$lt`, meaning "less than", you probably want document with `updated_at` less than your endGracePeriodInMillis.

Comment: I couldnt get you .. i have again updated my doubt .. can u brief me more

Comment: Edited the answer to contain more detailed explanation

Comment: yes @nimrod serok exactly i want as u explained ...but my problem is .. in the query it should come as only number like "$gt": 1653466067550 (which is giving results) but it is coming as "$gt": {"$numberLong": "1653466067550" - which is creating problem